# Cakephp custom validate return in textarea

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I would like to use custom validation for textarea because there will be a Slovak accents but when I will enter the new line throws me an error.
Please advise how to validate enter button? thank you

```
var $validate = array('text'=>array('custom'=>array(
    'rule' => array('custom', '/^[a-zA-Z0-9cšltžýáíéúóäônd".:,´()CŠLTŽÝÁÍÉÚÓND ]*$/i'),
    'message' => 'Zadávajte prosím len čísla alebo písmená')
        )
    );
```

Comment: Perhaps you need the `m` modifier to validate multi-line text.

Comment: Why does it have to be a custom validation? It seems like "nonempty" pretty much covers your regex right there.

Comment: I do not want link and etc. in this part

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom validation rule and I would suggest externalizing that to a model function.
Also your inline validation seems a bit broken to me.

So what you can do:

```
var $validate = array(
    'text' => array(
        'rule' => 'myNewCustomRule',
        'message' => 'Zadávajte prosím len čísla alebo písmená'
    ));
```

And the function in the model:

```
 function myNewCustomRule($custom) {
     //You may need to add here because the $data array is passed using the form field name as the key, you will have to extract the value to make the function generic
     //array_shift($custom);
     return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9cšltžýáíéúóäônd".:,´()CŠLTŽÝÁÍÉÚÓND ]*$/i', $custom);
 }
```